# Can't find difference between Fetch and JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch

I'm trying to do API request to a private API (hosted Itop), there's an example in the doc with JQuery Ajax but I did all my others calls with fetch and I wanted to do this one too but I don't get the right response.

The fetch method returns me a code 200 but with HTML instead of JSON (with a totally different content from the jQuery AJAX JSON one).

Here's the 2 functions:

```js
// Code made by myself - don't get the right response
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "accept": "application/json",
  },
  mode: "cors",
  accept: "application/json, text/javascript, *!/!*; q=0.01",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    auth_user: user,
    auth_pwd: password,
    json_data: JSON.stringify({
      "operation": "list_operations",
    })
  })
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

```js
// Code from the doc example - working
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    auth_user: user,
    auth_pwd: password,
    json_data: JSON.stringify({
      "operation": "list_operations"
    })
  },
  crossDomain: 'true'
})
  .then(
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(jqXHR);
    },
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.debug(jqXHR);
      console.log("ERROR !!\n" +
        "status: " + textStatus + " (" + jqXHR.status + ")\n" +
        "error: " + errorThrown);
    }
  );
```

Comment: have you set the content type to JSON for the request?

Comment: Did you check, using something like fiddler, whether there is any difference between the 2

Comment: I believe you'll need to set "Content-Type: application/JSON" header.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data

Comment: `with HTML instead of JSON` - is the content of the HTML at all useful

Comment: it's nothing to do with your issue, but `accept:` is not a valid request option (it's ignored though, so, nothing to do with your problem as I said)

Comment: Just to clarify what Bravo said, `accept` *is* a perfectly value request header, and your use of it inside `headers: {}` is fine. It's nonsense outside of `headers` through.

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, but are you able to see what request the server _receives_ or even what you're sending? I'd guess at a `content-type` error.

Comment: @Quentin - thanks for clarifying Mr Brave :p

Comment: @minism @Bravo I tried with `Content-Type: "application/json"` and the request didn't work because of CORS then I tried wih `Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` (the same as in the ajax request) and it did the same as before : I get an HTML page

Comment: Well, since you are not sending application/json where it works, setting it where it doesn't won't help

Comment: @Bravo the HTML data is completely different from the JSON one, I can't extract any useful information

Comment: right ... but does it contain any useful information at all - like some indication why you are receiving HTML instead of the expected JSON - we cant' see it, you need to analyse it

Comment: @Bravo no, just the login page as if I went on the page on my web browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery.ajax, when you pass `data` an object:

- it will be encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data
- jQuery will include a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header

In fetch, you are passing `body` a **string of JSON** and fetch will be including a `Content-Type: text/plain` header.

So:

- You are passing the wrong encoding of data
- You are passing a Content-Type that doesn't match what the server expects *or* what your data actually is

---

Pass `fetch` a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object.

This will be encoded with the correct format and `fetch` will infer the correct content type from it.

Comment: You mean a random URLSearchParams object ?

Comment: @MariusROBERT — No. One with the specific data you want to send. i.e. with auth_data, auth_pwd, and json_data in it.

Comment: auth_user and auth_pwd can be send through a URLSearchParams object ?

Comment: @MariusROBERT — Why would I have told you to use it if it wasn't going to work?

Comment: I already used URLSearchParams and I understood that it was completely different from body content. I just tried by setting the body content in a URLSearchParam and it did the same as before : sent me HTML

Comment: How did you try setting the body content there? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I added `+ new URLSearchParams({ auth_user: user, auth_pwd: password, json_data: JSON.stringify({ "operation": "list_operations", } ) } )` in fetch first parameter

Comment: @MariusROBERT — That `+` will try to convert the result into a number. The first parameter should be a URL not the form data. The data still needs to go in the body. It should be `body: new URL...`

Comment: Oh, ok, I had for habits to use URLSearchParams in the URL field, that works now, thanks. Could you edit your answer with the working code please